# Avoiding nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, nested-loops

I have a matrix `A` with dimension of `1024 * 307200` and another matrix `B` of dimension `1024 * 50`. I am performing `L2_norm` on these two matrices in a nested for loop to get my final matrix `C` as  `307200 * 50`.
You can find the code below:

```
    for i in range(307200):
        for l in range(50):
            C[i,l] =  numpy.linalg.norm(A[:,i] - B[:,l]))
```

As you see the dimension of my variables is huge which is leading to a very high latency. I want to avoid this nested loop since for each values of `i` and `l`, I am using the same function.

Is there any way to optimize the above loop?

Comment: "The same function" is not a determining factor. Suppose you want to set all the elements to `1` instead: then you *still* have to loop over all elements. But perhaps you can make it a *generator*.

Comment: You could make i and l into numpy arrays containing integers within your given ranges, initialize an empty array of all results, and use numpy vectorization to fill in the values of the empty array via i and l.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could replace the inner loop and your function with these matrix operations?

```
for i in range(307200):
    temp = A[:,i,np.newaxis] - B[:]
    C[i,:] = np.linalg.norm(temp, axis=0)
```

For smaller arrays, I got about 20 times lower running times. Perhaps you gain even more. In any case, plese make sure that you are receiving good results (on a smaller sets).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I like your idea. I just now edited the question since I used numpy.linalg.norm in place of my previous function. Could you do the required changes in your answer for the modified question. +1 given already :)

Comment: Its working fine :) my previous code took 280 secs and now its 27 secs. Thanx

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for letting me know about this thumb rule in stackoverflow . Just now accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** With OP's update and clarifications things get much simpler:

```
>>> def f_pp(A, B):
...     return np.sqrt(np.add.outer(np.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, A), np.einsum('il,il->l', B, B)) - 2*np.einsum('ij,il->jl', A, B))
...
```

end Update

You could use `np.einsum` and real arithmetic for a massive speedup:

```
>>> def f_pp(A, B):
...     Ar = A.view(float).reshape(*A.shape, 2)
...     Br = B.view(float).reshape(*B.shape, 2)
...     return np.sqrt(np.add.outer(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->j', Ar, Ar), np.einsum('ilk,ilk->l', Br, Br)) - 2*np.einsum('ijk,ilk->jl', Ar, Br))
...
```

For shapes `(1024, 3072)` and `(1024, 50)` I get a factor of about `40`.

Some explanation:

Real arithmetic: Unless numpy does some unbelievably smart optimizations I would expect a complex product like `x*x.conj()` to use 4 real multiplications. Knowing that the result is real we save two of those.

Writing `|A-B|^2` as `|A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A*B|`. This saves memory by avoiding the huge intermediate `A-B` of shape `(1024, 3072, 50)` (`(1024, 307200, 50)` in the full example) that a direct broadcasting approach would use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I like your idea. I just now edited the question since I used numpy.linalg.norm in place of my previous function. Could you do the required changes in your answer for the modified question. +1 given already :)

Comment: @Sansk do your changes change your result? Also, are your arrays actually of type `complex`? Your first version suggested it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, actually they are not complex and I figured out I dont need to do conjugate for L2 norm, I just used nump.linalg to calculate Norm. However, the result didn't changed much. Anycase, thanks for your code, I got to know something new. If you want to modify your answer based on my changes, you are free to do it. :)